# Is it possible to initialize an array at compile-time so it doesn't take time at run-time?

Tags: c++, runtime, metaprogramming, compile-time

If, for example, I want to create the Sieve of Eratosthenes up to 2 million, it will take a bit of time at run-time. Is there a way to reduce the run-time by using metaprogramming?

**Code for the Sieve (initializes std::bitset up to `const MILLION`):**

```
void initCiur(std::bitset<MILLION> &c)
{
    c[0] = c[1] = 1;
    for (int i=4; i <= MILLION; i+=2)
        c[i] = 1;
    for (int i=3; i*i <= MILLION; i+=2)
        if (!c[i])
            for (int j=3*i; j <= MILLION; j+=2*i)
                c[j] = 1;
}
```

Comment: use `constexpr` for `initCiur` function ?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to reduce the run-time by using metaprogramming?

#### Of course yes. I understand "[metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming)" very broadly, as any program  generating code (not just clever C++ templates).

On most [C++ implementations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) (e.g. if using some recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler on some [GNU/Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) operating system), a C++ [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) practically is a [textual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_file) [file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file). Read also the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).

So just configure your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (e.g. [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/)) to *generate* at build time (perhaps with a [Python](https://python.org/) or [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) script, or your C++ metaprogram) some C++ file, or some file that would be `#include`-d elsewhere. Or write your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) doing so.

BTW, this idea is not new: [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/) and [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [SWIG](https://swig.org/) do so (and recent GCC compilers -e.g. [GCC 10](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/)- have a dozen of specialized C++ code generators). And my abandoned project [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) did so.
And so do [RefPerSys](https://refpersys.org/) and [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) (for primes numbers useful in hashtables, both are projects I started). Parts of the [`primes_rps.cc` file](https://gitlab.com/bstarynk/refpersys/-/blob/master/primes_rps.cc) have been machine generated (see comments inside it).

In *some* cases, a clever [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) could optimize `constexpr` things. Be aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) which states that it is not *always* possible to cleverly optimize. See also [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report.

You could also be interested in code generating libraries such as [asmjit](https://asmjit.com/) or [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), or in generating [plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) at runtime (on Linux, you would use [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html), but read first the [C++ dlopen mini-howto](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/C++-dlopen/) then [*how to write shared libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)).

PS. with other operating systems (e.g. Windows) and C++ compilers things could be different, but most of the ideas above are reusable. Read the documentation of your C++ [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) and of your [operating system](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/). In [cross-compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) approaches, you may need more tricks.